# Why axios ignore headers?

Tags: javascript, axios

axios ignore headers in this code:

```
static async likePost(jwt: string | null){

    const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/api/feed/like`, {
        headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwt
        }
    });

    return response
}
```

but add headers to this code:

```
static async getProfileByJWT(jwt: string| null) {

    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/profile`, {
        headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwt
        }
    });

    return response.data.candidate
}
```

what do I need to do to fix this problem?

I try to adding default headers to even request, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post` takes 3 arguments `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])` so the call should look like this

```
const response = await axios.post(
  `http://localhost:4000/api/feed/like`, 
  {/* data you want to post goes here */},  
  {
        headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwt
        }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add defaults headers ([config_defaults](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults)) for all requests, you can set them:

```js
// Set config defaults when creating the instance
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
});

// Alter defaults after instance has been created

// Alter default for all requests
instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;

// Alter defaults only for post request
instance.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

// Alter defaults only for get request
instance.defaults.headers.get['x-rapid-api-key'] = API_KEY;
```

Answer (score 1):

To send an Axios POST request with headers, you need to use the headers option. With axios.post(), the first parameter is the URL, the 2nd parameter is the request body, and the 3rd parameter is the options. For example, below is how you set the authorization header on an HTTP POST request.

```
    const res = await axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', { hello: 'world' }, {
  headers: {
    'authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
  }
});
```

In Your case, You didn't provide data. in post request, You need to provide body. If you haven't body data, you need to keep empty.